# Singleton instance instantiation

Tags: java, static, synchronization, singleton, volatile

I am starting to get used to the keywords `static` and `volatile` in Java. In regards to a singleton class I am building, why do I see the following design?

```
public class Singleton{
    private static volatile Singleton _instance; 

    public static Singleton getInstance(){

       if(_instance == null){
           synchronized(Singleton.class){
               if(_instance == null)
                   _instance = new Singleton();
           }

       }
       return _instance;

    }
}
```

instead of this one?

```
public class Singleton{ 
    private static volatile Singleton _instance = new Singleton();

    public static Singleton getInstance(){
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Does the first design have any advantage over the second? The only advantage I can see is that the second design synchronizes the whole method, which can require blocking the whole method. But my counter-thought to that is that the method is only one line and wouldn't block noticeably at all, right?

Comment: What does "blocking noticeably" mean? Just because *we* can't notice assembly-language instruction times doesn't mean they don't matter in real life.

Comment: I am pretty sure the first example does not need two checks for a null _instance.  So the second check could be removed. In this class there is no way for the instance to go from new'd to null.

Comment: @user619818 The second check is necessary, because another thread may already have initialized the instance since the previous check.

Comment: Ah if you get a context switch between threads.  OK.

Comment: @DaveNewton When I say "blocking noticeably", I mean there is no difference in the time it takes to call each getInstance() method from each design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have preferred to add a comment but it seems I am not allowed to do that quite yet.

The first example is Double-checked locking, which is no longer broken in Java:

> As of J2SE 5.0, this problem has been fixed. The volatile keyword now ensures that multiple threads handle the singleton instance correctly.
>   ~ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

The Idea of Double-checked locking is to hold off on creating the singleton object until it is needed, and to lock the object with synchronized as little as possible.

The second example would create the singleton as soon as the class was loaded (probably at start-up), regardless of whether it was ever used.

Both examples are thread-safe, and as of J2SE 5.0 perfectly usable.  It just depends on then you want to take the cost of creating the singleton object, and weather holding a object in memory that never gets used is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the second one performs "lazy" initialization, so in case instantiation of your class can take a lot of time and you are not sure you need instance of this class in your application. In this case you can create an instance "on demand". 
As per multithreading environment - both designs are thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

First example is useful for multithreaded applications, but is proven **not to be safe** unless you use the `volatile` keyword. It's called **Double-checked locking singleton pattern**.

The idea is: 
 - to check if the object is `null` so if it's not to return it and avoid locking.
 - if it's `null`, lock *lock* the class.
 - check again if it's `null` because some other thread might have locked it before the current thread.
 - if it's still null instantiate it.

Using volatile fixes the problem because it ensures that other threads will not read the variable until the previous thread finishes, but still, locking and synchronizing are expensive operations in the means of CPU time.

The proper way to do it is to use the **The Solution of Bill Pugh**:

```
public class Singleton {
    // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
    private Singleton() { }

    /**
    * SingletonHolder is loaded on the first execution of Singleton.getInstance() 
    * or the first access to SingletonHolder.INSTANCE, not before.
    */
    private static class SingletonHolder { 
            public static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
            return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

It's thread safe and the correct way to do it. It's also a lazy initialization as the inner class is loaded only when they are referenced and **static** keyword ensures only one instance per class.

Your second example works, but it's not lazily initialized.

Comment: Why don't you need to specify the INSTANCE variable as volatile? Could it be possible that each thread has its own cache of INSTANCE and could become stale?

Comment: `volatile` ensures that other threads will not read it until the previous thread finishes with it.

Comment: So without setting INSTANCE as volatile, isn't it possible that two threads could modify the instance at the same time and overwrite one another?

Comment: The article is from 2001, and no longer valid under 1.5+, whether or not it's the best way to do it is a separate issue.

Comment: @Darijan Well, no.  1.  Declaring a field final ensures there will be no visibility issues.  2.  Even if you don't declare it final, but effectively immutable (which it is in this case) since it is initialized inline as a static field, it will not have visibility issues either